# Exit status of pipe with timeout command behaves differently in interactive shell vs shell script

Tags: shell-script, pipe, posix, timeout

Interactive `sh` shell session:

```
$ sh
$ timeout 1 yes | sed -n s/a/b/p ; echo $?
Terminated
143
$
```

Non-interactive script via `sh -c`:

```
$ sh -c 'timeout 1 yes | sed -n s/a/b/p ; echo $?'
0
$
```

Why do those two examples produce different exit codes?

Comment: [Similar issue on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1260918/432690).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`timeout` (GNU `timeout` at least) by default tries to run the command in a new process group and kills that process group with SIGTERM upon timeout.

That way, if that command spawned more processes, they are also killed upon timeout.

```
~$ strace -fze  '/[sg]etpg|exec|kill|exit' sh -c 'timeout 1 sleep 2 | sleep 3'
execve("/usr/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "timeout 1 sleep 2 | sleep 3"], 0x7fffe2349230 /* 69 vars */) = 0
strace: Process 316058 attached
strace: Process 316059 attached
[pid 316058] execve("/usr/bin/timeout", ["timeout", "1", "sleep", "2"], 0x561e384e43a8 /* 69 vars */) = 0
[pid 316059] execve("/usr/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "3"], 0x561e384e41c8 /* 69 vars */) = 0
[pid 316058] setpgid(0, 0)              = 0
strace: Process 316060 attached
[pid 316060] execve("/usr/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "2"], 0x7ffc3ef29910 /* 69 vars */) = 0
[pid 316058] --- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_TIMER, si_timerid=0, si_overrun=0, si_int=0, si_ptr=NULL} ---
[pid 316058] kill(316060, SIGTERM)      = 0
[pid 316060] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=316058, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 316058] kill(0, SIGTERM)           = 0
[pid 316058] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=316058, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 316060] +++ killed by SIGTERM +++
[pid 316058] kill(316060, SIGCONT <unfinished ...>
)                                       = 0
[pid 316058] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=316060, si_uid=1000, si_status=SIGTERM, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid 316058] kill(0, SIGCONT)           = 0
[pid 316058] --- SIGCONT {si_signo=SIGCONT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=316058, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 316058] +++ exited with 124 +++
[pid 316057] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=316058, si_uid=1000, si_status=124, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid 316059] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=316059, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

See `timeout` doing a `setpgid(0, 0)` (same as `setpgrp()`) to create a new process group, you see it doing `kill(316060, SIGTERM)` to kill `sleep 2`, but also `kill(0, SIGTERM)` to kill its own process group (which it created earlier) which would have also killed processes spawned by `sleep 2` if any (none in this case).

Now, when job control is enabled in the shell (like when interactive or called with the `-m` / `-o monitor` option), in:

```
timeout 1 sleep 2 | sleep 3
```

The shell already starts `timeout` and `sleep 3` in a new process group, and in most shells, the process group leader will be the one that runs `timeout`.

So when `timeout` does `setpgrp()`, same as `setpgid(0, 0)`, it will not create a new process group, that just becomes a no-op. So the process group will still contain `timeout`, the process it spawns to run `sleep 2`, and `sleep 3` which was put there beforehand by the shell.

```
~$ strace -fze  '/[sg]etpg|exec|kill|exit' sh -o monitor  -c 'timeout 1 sleep 2 | sleep 3'
execve("/usr/bin/sh", ["sh", "-o", "monitor", "-c", "timeout 1 sleep 2 | sleep 3"], 0x7ffeb8e13640 /* 69 vars */) = 0
getpgrp()                               = 318590
setpgid(0, 318593)                      = 0
strace: Process 318594 attached
[pid 318593] setpgid(318594, 318594)    = 0
[pid 318594] setpgid(0, 318594)         = 0
strace: Process 318595 attached
[pid 318595] setpgid(0, 318594)         = 0
[pid 318593] setpgid(318595, 318594)    = 0
[pid 318595] execve("/usr/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "3"], 0x557fde7871c8 /* 69 vars */) = 0
[pid 318594] execve("/usr/bin/timeout", ["timeout", "1", "sleep", "2"], 0x557fde7873a8 /* 69 vars */) = 0
[pid 318594] setpgid(0, 0)              = 0
strace: Process 318596 attached
[pid 318596] execve("/usr/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "2"], 0x7ffc60f34c60 /* 69 vars */) = 0
[pid 318594] --- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_TIMER, si_timerid=0, si_overrun=0, si_int=0, si_ptr=NULL} ---
[pid 318594] kill(318596, SIGTERM)      = 0
[pid 318596] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=318594, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 318596] +++ killed by SIGTERM +++
[pid 318594] kill(0, SIGTERM <unfinished ...>
)                                       = 0
[pid 318595] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=318594, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 318594] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=318594, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 318595] +++ killed by SIGTERM +++
[pid 318594] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=318596, si_uid=1000, si_status=SIGTERM, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid 318593] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=318595, si_uid=1000, si_status=SIGTERM, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
Terminated
[pid 318594] kill(318596, SIGCONT)      = 0
[pid 318594] kill(0, SIGCONT)           = 0
[pid 318594] --- SIGCONT {si_signo=SIGCONT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=318594, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 318594] +++ exited with 124 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=318594, si_uid=1000, si_status=124, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
setpgid(0, 318590)                      = 0
+++ exited with 143 +++
```

This time, the `kill(0, SIGTERM)` kills the process running `sleep 3` as it's also in the 318594 process group (as put there by the shell with `setpgid(318595, 318594)`).

In:

```
sleep 2 | timeout 1 sleep 3 | sleep 4
```

You'll find that the pipeline lasts 4 seconds and only `sleep 3` is killed after 1 second as this time, the process group created by the shell is led by the process running `sleep 2`, so `timeout` is able to create a new process group for itself (and its child `sleep 3`) which is different from the process group created by the shell for the 3 commands in the pipeline (and as a result, you'll find that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> don't work properly whilst `timeout` is running as `timeout` is not running in the foreground process group).

When run with `--foreground`, `timeout` skips creating that extra process group and doesn't do a `kill(0, SIGTERM)` to kill its own process group, so the behaviour is more consistent but means grandchildren processes are not killed.

```
$ strace -fze  '/[sg]etpg|ioctl|exec|kill|exit' sh -o monitor  -c 'timeout --foreground 1 sh -c "sleep 2; exit" | sleep 3'
execve("/usr/bin/sh", ["sh", "-o", "monitor", "-c", "timeout --foreground 1 sh -c \"sl"...], 0x7ffe289c2910 /* 69 vars */) = 0
ioctl(10, TIOCGPGRP, [331754])          = 0
getpgrp()                               = 331754
setpgid(0, 331757)                      = 0
ioctl(10, TIOCSPGRP, [331757])          = 0
strace: Process 331758 attached
[pid 331757] setpgid(331758, 331758)    = 0
[pid 331758] setpgid(0, 331758)         = 0
[pid 331758] ioctl(10, TIOCSPGRP, [331758]) = 0
strace: Process 331759 attached
[pid 331757] setpgid(331759, 331758)    = 0
[pid 331759] setpgid(0, 331758)         = 0
[pid 331759] ioctl(10, TIOCSPGRP, [331758]) = 0
[pid 331759] execve("/usr/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "3"], 0x55dc52f76418 /* 69 vars */) = 0
[pid 331758] execve("/usr/bin/timeout", ["timeout", "--foreground", "1", "sh", "-c", "sleep 2; exit"], 0x55dc52f763a8 /* 69 vars */) = 0
strace: Process 331760 attached
[pid 331760] execve("/usr/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "sleep 2; exit"], 0x7fff756826c0 /* 69 vars */) = 0
strace: Process 331761 attached
[pid 331761] execve("/usr/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "2"], 0x557447790168 /* 69 vars */) = 0
[pid 331758] --- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_TIMER, si_timerid=0, si_overrun=0, si_int=0, si_ptr=NULL} ---
[pid 331758] kill(331760, SIGTERM)      = 0
[pid 331760] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=331758, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 331760] +++ killed by SIGTERM +++
[pid 331758] +++ exited with 124 +++
[pid 331757] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=331758, si_uid=1000, si_status=124, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid 331761] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 331759] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=331759, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
ioctl(10, TIOCSPGRP, [331757])          = 0
ioctl(10, TIOCSPGRP, [331754])          = 0
setpgid(0, 331754)                      = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

`sh` is killed, but not `sleep 2`.

That also explains why in an interactive shell in a terminal:

```
sh -c 'timeout 10 cat; exit'
```

Or:

```
sleep 10 | timeout 10 cat /dev/tty
```

`cat` can't read from the terminal. It ends up being suspended when it tries as it's in a new process group, so no longer in the foreground process group of the terminal.

Again, adding the `--foreground` option avoids the problem.